# Order of pages in tcolorbox with "tcbincludepdf"

Tags: tcolorbox

I need to create a document from multiple pdf pages, and use the "tcbincludepdf" from the tcolorbox package to do that.

However, I cannot manipulate the page order. The following MWE produces a pdf, and in the attached screenshot I marked the page order I would like to have in red.

MWE:
**To create the PDF source file:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centering
\scalebox{30}{1}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{2}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{3}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{4}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{5}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{6}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{7}\newpage
\scalebox{30}{8}
\end{document}
```

**To create the PDF output file:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    colframe = white,
    raster height=\textheight,raster equal skip=0pt,blank,
    colback = white,
    colbacktitle = black!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    center title,
    graphics pages = {1,2,3,4, 5,6,7},
 title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{1.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order in the `graphics pages` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    colframe = white,
    raster height=\textheight,raster equal skip=0pt,blank,
    colback = white,
    colbacktitle = black!50,
    fonttitle = \small\ttfamily,
    boxsep = 0pt,
    toptitle = 1mm,
    bottomtitle = 1mm,
    center title,
    raster halign=right, % to right align the last page
    graphics pages = {2,1,4,3,6,5,7}, %<-- order
 title = {MWE\ [\imagepage]}]
\tcbincludepdf{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost perfect, however what about the 7th page?

Comment: `raster halign=right,`